# External object path containing space

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

I'm struggling with integrating the `psvince.dll` library to detect a running application on install and uninstall. The problem is that the path to the `external` keyword contains a whitespace that breaks the whole thing up. The code is as follows:

```
#define INSTALL_PATH "{pf}\My Plugin"

[Files]
Source: psvince.dll; flags: dontcopy
Source: psvince.dll; DestDir: "{#INSTALL_PATH}"

[Code]
function IsModuleLoadedU(modulename: String ):  Boolean;
external 'IsModuleLoaded@{#INSTALL_PATH}\psvince.dll stdcall uninstallonly' ;
```

The code yields `Invalid External` error.

The `INSTALL_PATH` macro is used to specfiy the target app installation directory, so that the user does not have to specify it. I'm also using it in other statements.

I've tried quoting the point where macro is used, splitting the string into multiple ones joined with `+`, to no avail.

Whole `psvince` code is available [here](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Call_psvince.dll_on_install_and_uninstall).

Comment: It will be copied over there during installation, and the only possibility that it would be removed is user's action. In this case actually nothing can help you recover from this situation.

Comment: @TLama, added ```[Files]```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{app}` instead of hard-coding the path.

You can still provide a default path via `DefaultDirName` and prevent the user from changing this via `DisableDirPage` if you wish, but you should **always** set `{app}` to something appropriate and use it throughout your installer, or you invite problems.

Comment: Although you're right with this suggestion, it is a bug in IS compiler. You should be able to specify path like e.g. `...@{app}\Uninst Libs\Library.dll` what you can't due to the space in the path. [even though I'm not fan of using spaces in paths at all, this should be compilable]

Comment: Follow the windows convention and quote the path?

Comment: @Marco, quoted path causes the same compilation error. However, it seems that it accepts `#32` instead of space char. Strange...

Comment: @Miral, worked like a charm, thanks! In addition to `DefaultDirName` i also had to add `CreateAppDir` setting.

Comment: @kroolik: you need `CreateAppDir=yes`, which is the default.  So you'd just need to remove any `CreateAppDir=no` you may have previously specified.